# Unity Framework: Chain up Resolution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to deduplicate registration in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12723867/is-it-possible-to-deduplicate-registration-in-unity)

I am trying to build up a resolution chain using unity xml configuration.
What I got is something like that:

```
interface IFoo{}
interface IBar : IFoo{}
class Impl : IBar{}
```

The configuration I use looks similar to the following:

```
<unity xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <container>
    <register type="IBar" mapTo="Impl"/>
    <register type "IFoo" mapTo="IBar"/>
  </container>
</unity>
```

When I invoke

```
unityContainer.Resolve<IFoo>()
```

I receive an exception telling me that IBar can not be constucted.
I would like Unity to re-resolve the mapped type here and return Impl.

Any Ideas how this can be done?

Comment: This is not correct, I am not looking for deduplication. I need injection/chaining!

Answer (score 2):

If you use *fluent registration*, you can use `InjectionFactory`:

```
 container.RegisterType<IBar, Impl>();
 container.RegisterType<IFoo>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IBar>()));

 var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();
```

But unluckily, `InjectionFactory` does not exist in xml configuration, so you have to parse xml by yourself.

Comment: This is a start, but I need to do it in xml...

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not do this. You could write a container extension to do it; replace the type mapping strategy that repeatedly looks up mapping until there were not more mappings and then try to resolve where you end up.

It was a conscious decision to build it this way; it was felt that chaining registrations like this would just confuse people. In the example it's clear, but realistic config files have dozens of types, and it would quickly become impossible to discover which type you're actually configuring.

So in your case, I'd suggest just doing:

```
<register type="IFoo" mapTo="Impl"/>
```

and consider it good.